# Google Custom Search Python Shopping Results Only?

Tags: python, google-api, google-custom-search, google-api-python-client

How would I go about using the Google Custom Search API, using the python GCS library, to only return Google Shopping results?

I have the basic implementation already for standard search queries, which searches the whole web and returns related sites, but how would I only return shopping results?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'search outside of google'checkbox in the dashboard. you will get the same result after you check it. it takes me a while to find it out. the default sitting is only return search result inside of all google websites.

Comment: Sorry, do you happen to know which setting or section this is under? Thank you.

Comment: @Questionnaire I forgot, but it should in the dashboard for GCS api

Comment: I don't believe this is what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to return ONLY shopping results from a google search.